# how to place font-awesome arrow icon center vertically

Tags: css, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

```css
.btnup, .btndown{
     display:inline-block;
     font-size:20px;
     background:#ddd;
     border-radius:5px;
     cursor:pointer;
     width:25px;
     line-height:30px;
     height:30px;
     color:#999;
     text-align:center;
     margin:0 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <i class="fas fa-angle-up btnup" id='btnup'></i>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down btndown" id='btndown'></i>
```

How to place the arrows on center vertically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add top and bottom padding (and subtract those values from the `height`setting):

```css
.btnup, .btndown{
     display:inline-block;
     font-size:20px;
     background:#ddd;
     border-radius:5px;
     cursor:pointer;
     width:25px;
     line-height:30px;
     height:20px;
     color:#999;
     text-align:center;
     margin:0 5px;
      padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <i class="fas fa-angle-up btnup" id='btnup'></i>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down btndown" id='btndown'></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the FA icon inside another element, which would be your gray background element, or you could add these CSS properties:

```
        height:25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
```

Basically reducing height, but compensating for it with padding-top, which forces the FA arrow icons down to the center of the gray area.

Answer (score 0):

the `line-height` its being overriden by font-awesome, add `!important` to make it take yours

```css
.btnup,
.btndown {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 30px!important;
  height: 30px;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fas fa-angle-up btnup" id='btnup'></i>
<i class="fas fa-angle-down btndown" id='btndown'></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with `height`, and `padding-top`:

```css
.btnup, .btndown{
     display:inline-block;
     font-size:20px;
     background:#ddd;
     border-radius:5px;
     cursor:pointer;
     width:25px;
     line-height:10px;
      padding-top: 5px;
     height:24px;
     color:#999;
     text-align:center;
     margin:0 5px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <i class="fas fa-angle-up btnup" id='btnup'></i>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down btndown" id='btndown'></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap a `<span>` around the character and use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to position it in the center.

```css
.btnup,
.btndown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontal alignment */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #999;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="btnup"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
<span class="btndown"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
```